# Outlook email on two different user accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am unable to receive incoming emails on my email account that I recently set on on my new user account.

I used to be able to receive emails on my local user account but after I started using my server account (and setting up my Outlook email on the outlook app) I was not able to receive any emails.

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure your email is backed up, then remove (delete) the Outlook Profile (Control Panel, Mail), restart the computer and make the email accounts again. Start with one account, make sure it works, then add the second account.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by server account? Can you receive emails correctly on the web mail? Can you send out successfully?

What's your account type? Exchange， POP or IMAP？

We can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

Similar Thread: [Unable to receive emails from exchange](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5dd97c20-cd0e-4176-a48c-7cb721660158/unable-to-receive-emails-from-exchange?forum=outlook)